# Given a integer N greater than zero. How many sequences of 1's and 2's are there

Tags: combinatorics

Given a integer N greater than zero.
How many sequences of 1's and 2's are there such that sum of the numbers in the sequence = N ?
(not necessary that every sequence must contain both 1 and 2 )
example :
for N = 2 ; 11,2 => ans = 2 sequences of 1's and 2's
for N = 3 ; 11,12,21 => ans = 3 sequences of 1's and 2's

Comment: It's so http://math.stackexchange.com/ if you ask me.

Comment: Can You provide me its solution please ?

Comment: Still there is obvious way to enumerate them all - you start with sequence of N ones, then replace 11 with 2 one time in all possible places, then replace 11 with 2 two times in all possible places and so on until you end up with sequence of 2s or sequence of 2s just single 1 (in all possible positions)

Comment: Thanks I will try

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's math, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

One can think of a recursive formula, for instance by characterizing the last digits. For instance, a sequence of N+1 can be obtained by concatenating a sequence of N and a 1, or a sequence of N-1 and a 2. So it gives:

R(N+1) = R(N) + R(N-1)

So we have a Fibonacci-type sequence with R(1)=1 and R(2)=2.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

It gives [image: R(N)=F(N+1)=(A^(N+1)-B^(N+1))/sqrt(5)]

where [image: A=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}] and [image: B=-1/A].

So you can program the answer using a constant number of operations.